# Use URL based on razor method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to redirect to particular page.
For that I am using some Javascript function in MVC project as::

```
function rootUrl(url) {                                                    
    var _rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
    var x = url;
    if (url.indexOf(_rootUrl) != 0) {
        x = _rootUrl + "/" + url;
        x = x.replace(/\/\//g, "/").replace(/\/\//g, "/");
    }
    return x;
};
```

which is being used as ::

```
var url = rootUrl("Home/Company/") + $(this).val();
window.location.href = url;
```

But I am getting wrong URL in my browser as::

```
http://localhost:60294/Home/Company/@Url.Content(%22~%22)/Home/Company/7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `Url.Action()` directly which gives you url relative to root directory, instead of creating a javascript messy function:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Company","Home")' + $(this).val();
```

Here,**Home** is the name of Controller and **Company** is the action of it

Answer (score 1):

You can't access razor in Js file. When I need the urls from Razor in Js I just define them in the `view`, like:

```
<script>
    var _rootUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
</script>
```

This will work

Comment: where OP mentioned that it in js file?

Comment: I hope is defined in js file because define an entire function in the html view isn't a good coding. Otherwise the razor did not work otherwise the result would never have been like
"http://localhost:60294/Home/Company/@Url.Content(%22~%22)/Home/Company/7"